# $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\cap)$ - is a group or not?

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to prove that $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\cap)$ is a group but I'm not really sure my proof is correct. When checking for the identity element I found that for every $A$ in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ the identity element is $A$ because

$A \cap A = A \cap A = A$

Regarding the inverse, I found that the inverse is also $A$ because

$A \cap A = A \cap A$ = identity element

Is this true or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The identity element is unique in a group !!!

Comment: the identity has to be global, so there needs to be _one_ identity element that works for _all_ A

Comment: hint: it's not a group

Comment: If it is a group, the identity must be $\Bbb N$, since it is the only set one can intersect with itself to not change it. But then, inverses cannot exist since intersection of a set with another set can never product a larger set. So if $A\subset\Bbb N$ is proper, $A\cap B\ne\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in a group the only element $x$ with $x*x=x$ is the neutral element. So by the very fact that $A\cap A=A$ for all elements and there are several $A$ possible, we see that this is not a group

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $A\cap A=A$ does not in fact mean that $A$ is the identity. You need to find a $\textit{single}$ element $x$ such that $A\cap x=A$ for every $A\in P(N)$. Once you find the actual identity element, you can use it to find the inverse of an element (if such an inverse exists - if it doesn't exist, then you can't have a group).

To make this obvious, consider the power set of a set with two elements: 
$$P(2)=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$$

Then $\{a\}\cap\{a\}=\{a\}$, but $\{a\}\cap\{b\}=\emptyset\ne\{b\}$, so $\{a\}$ cannot be the identity element.